# Error when using numpy to encode categorical features of dataset

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I use the following function to encode the categorical features of my dataset (it has 27 features where 11 of them is categorical):

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
def features_encoding(data):
    columnsToEncode = list(data.select_dtypes(include=['category', 'object']))
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    for feature in columnsToEncode:
        try:
            data[feature] = le.fit_transform(data[feature])
        except:
            continue
    return data
```

But I get this error:

```
FutureWarning: numpy not_equal will not check object identity in the future. The comparison did not return the same result as suggested by the identity (`is`)) and will change.
      flag = np.concatenate(([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1]))
```

I don't understand this error. Kindly, can someone explain what is it about and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly being caused by there being `np.nan` more than once in an array of `dtype=object` that is passed into `np.unique`.

This may help clarify what's going on:

```
>>> np.nan is np.nan
True
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
>>> np.array([np.nan], dtype=object) == np.array([np.nan], dtype=object)
FutureWarning: numpy equal will not check object identity in the future. The comparison did not return the same result as suggested by the identity (`is`)) and will change.
array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

So when comparing two arrays of `dtype=object`, numpy checks if the return of the comparison function is `False` when both objects being compared are the exact same. Because right now it assumes that all objects compare equal to themselves, but that will be changed at same time in the future.

All in all, it's just a warning, so you can ignore it, at least for now...

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate your answer